# Bar diagram with bar diagram overlay in relation

Tags: javascript, charts

weird title I know...
I'm currently developing a simple page that displays temperature and humidity in a simple bar chart.

I couldn't find any solution how to display my temperature in bars and overlay these bars with humidity information which is displayed within these bars (in relation to their size). Given a Temperature of 22 degrees celsius and 50 Percent relative humidity, I'd like to display a bar which is half-filled with another color.

The current solution is to display the temperature as bars and the humidity as an overlayed line chart:

[image: current chart]

but this makes the temperature bar very tiny.
Any ideas which type of chart I should give a try?

I'm open for any solution (preferrably JS)

Answer (score 0):

actually there was no existing solution, but the best for me was the multi axes chart of Highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

[image]